# How to find top 20% percent of volunteers from a large dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerquery, cumulative-frequency

I run a volunteering program where volunteers visit seniors in care homes. Each time a volunteer visits, they complete a survey that shows me the date of the visit and the time they spent with the senior.

I want to find the top 20% of volunteers in 1) their number of visits and 2) their total volunteering time in minutes.

I did some research and wanted to make a cumulative frequency graph to do so. However, I have over 7000 individual survey entries.

After downloading that data, the table looks like Figure 1. What can I do to get frequency graphs, like Figures 2 and 3, for thousands of entries?

[Figure 1. Mock survey entries of volunteer hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzpl.png)
[Figure 2. Number of visits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM8hD.png)
[Figure 3. Volunteer time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Fqv.png)

I have basic knowledge of Excel. I've tried using Pivot Tables. Would I need PowerQuery, Macros, etc. to do so?

Any advice will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You will need to use [Excel Power Pivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-power-pivot-in-microsoft-excel-fdfcf944-7876-424a-8437-1a6c1043a80b). Then once you have your data in there, you can use `RANKX` function. See [Introducing the RANKX Function](https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/power-pivot-principles/ppp-introducing-the-rankx-function)

Comment: The new Groupby function does a similar thing, if you have it.

Comment: the simplest way is =PERCENTILE(CELL RANGE, QUINTILE) to find your top 20% 7000 records should not be to big